How to know the access condition of EF_MSISDN in SIM card?
I am connected to the phone (USB Debug mode, plus enabling 3GPP AT commands). I need to write my own MSISDN in the SIM. I managed to do it in Physical SIM, but for the eSIM I got an error. I suspect that the EF_MSISDN in the esIM has some write restriction.
For Physical SIM
AT
OK
AT+CPBS?
+CPBS: "SM",0,500
OK
AT+CPBS="ON"
OK
AT+CPBS?
+CPBS: "ON",0,3
OK
AT+CPBR=1
OK
AT+CPBW=,"+123456789"
OK
AT+CPBR=1
+CPBR: 1,"+123456789",145,""
OK
AT+CNUM
+CNUM: "","+123456789",145
OK
To apply for esIM, I need to first run
AT$QCPBMPREF=3
This will point to the local address book for SIM2 (Which is an eSIM in my case)
AT+CPBS="ON"
OK
but the command AT+CPBW gave error. I doubt that the eSIM manufacture has set the write permission for the EF_MSISDN file to be "ADM" so only the Telecom Operator can change it.
The question is : How can I verify that the EF_MSISDN write permission is set to "ADM" ? Is there any AT command to know this ? Or any way around ?

The filesystem permissions (known was "Security attributes") are part of the File Control Parameters that are returned at the time you select a file. You can get that FCP TLV either

using SELECT to select a file like EF.MSISDN
using STATUS to get the FCP of the currently selected file

See ETSI TS 102 221 Section 11.1.1 / 11.1.2 for the reference.
The returned data will contain the security attributes (depending on their encoding) in tag '8B', '8C' or 'AB'.
In most cases, the "referenced" format is used.  See 9.2.4 to 9.2.7 of ETSI TS 102 221 for the encoding.

Thanks for your reply can you please share lazy commands to do it as I am not that type of expert and also from where shall I send these commands (e.g. from putty by AT commands)
